# How to extract numeric elements from an entire row in a dataframe, using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[Ex - Extract all numbers from the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXLa6.png)

Comment: What are you looking to extract from that? Question needs more information if you want an answer

Comment: pls provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

can you give csv file of data frame and which numbers you want to extract?

here is one way for a similar data frame

```
 #code to extract no. from a dataframe
from numpy.core.arrayprint import printoptions
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict={'0':['almarai investors  according to investor type loss','almarai investors  according to investor type loss',
'savola group','hh prince','governmenatla','other'],
'1':['31 dec2020','percent','34.5%','23.7%','56.5%','9.1%'],'2':[np.nan,np.nan,1,1,5,4125],
'font':['Normal','Normal','Normal','Normal','Normal','Normal']}

df= pd.DataFrame(dict)
 

df_numerics=df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
print(df_numerics)
```